# The name 'Heal' does not exist in current context CS0103

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

So I'm having this error saying 'Heal' doesn't exist in current context. I can't tell if I'm being really stupid or if visual studio is being annoying. These files are both in the same directory.

I've been trying to find an answer for ages, but can't find anything. I'm guessing I'm having a brain fart or something.

The error occurs in the 'Item' file when I call the healPlayer function from the 'Heal' file.

File 1:
Item.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Item{

   public int cost;
   public int sellprice;
   public bool stackable;

   public Item(int HealAmount)
   {
       heals = HealAmount;
   }
   public static int heals;

   public static void use()
   {
       if (heals > 0)
       {
           Heal.healPlayer(heals);
       }
   }

}
```

File 2:
Heal.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Heal : MonoBehaviour{

   public static void healPlayer(int heals)
   {
       Player.ccurrenthealth = Player.ccurrenthealth + heals;
       if (Player.ccurrenthealth > Player.chealth)
       {
           Player.ccurrenthealth = Player.chealth;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add a language tag and also search for the error message you receive. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Nothing seems to stand out as a problem. Couple of things - (1) Are you sure the healPlayer method code is not reached and its erroring out before that? (2) I would try copying these 2 classes to a test project and check if there is still an issue.

Comment: Try [recreating project files](https://nagachiang.github.io/unity-generating-visual-studio-projects-for-packages/) in unity it sometimes gets it wrong especially if you have downloaded new version of unity recently